# Not able to convert response data into JSON

Tags: reactjs, api, async-await

I'm able to get response from API, but not able to convert response into Json and not able to return  the data. It simply return null.

```
 const responseData = async () => {
    try{
        const response = await axios.get('https://randomuser.me/api')
        console.log(response) // console object
        
      const jsonData = await response.json()
        return jsonData;
    }catch(err){
      console.error(err)
    }
}

    export default function App() {
  const [randomUserDataJson,setRandomUserDataJson] = useState('')

  useEffect( () => {
    responseData().then(randomdata => {
      setRandomUserDataJson(randomdata || 'not found') 
   })

  }, []);
 return (
    <div >
      <pre>
          <p>{randomUserDataJson}</p>
      </pre>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Output

```
not found
```

Comment: have you tried const jsonData = await response.json(), try this: const jsonData = await response.data.json()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly return the `axios` response nothing but the promise and access the result using `then` method.

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [randomUserDataJson, setRandomUserDataJson] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    responseData().then((randomdata) => {
      const data = JSON.stringify(randomdata.data);
      setRandomUserDataJson(data || "not found");
    });
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <pre>
        <p>{randomUserDataJson}</p>
      </pre>
    </div>
  );
}

const responseData = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get("https://randomuser.me/api");
    return response;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};
```

codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-bush-iicqm?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do `const jsonData = await response.json()`, axios will deserialize the response to JS Object for you. Just remove that line and it would work. Also, you can't render JS object as a child of a React Component, so it has to be stringified.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const responseData = async () => {
  try{
      const response = await axios.get('https://randomuser.me/api')
      console.log(response) // console object
    
      return response;
  }catch(err){
    console.error(err)
  }
}

  export default function App() {
const [randomUserDataJson,setRandomUserDataJson] = useState('')

useEffect( () => {
  responseData().then(randomdata => {
    setRandomUserDataJson(randomdata || 'not found') 
 })

}, []);
return (
  <div >
    <pre>
        <p>{JSON.stringify(randomUserDataJson, null, 2)}</p>
    </pre>
  </div>
);
}
```